# Excel VBA: Search sheet for specific string when initializing userform

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to explore some of the possibilities in VBA, and wanted to create a expenses tracking sheet. (Mine will be specific for sports gambling, as it's legal where i live, but could be altered to household expenses, travel expenses etc.)

The user inputs bets (1 pr. row) and sets its outcome to "Not Decided" via a seperate userform

Then when the game is decided, the user needs to update the outcome of that bet, via another userform, which is where i'm stuck currently. I'd hoped that i could get the form to have two textboxes with the relevant information (date of bet and description) that populate with the data from the row with the outcome set as "Not Decided".

The code i've tried to assemble, which runs without error, but doesn't output anything is below. I've tried to add a messagebox with the "Beskrivelse" variant but it returned empty. I can't figure out if it runs correctly but doesn't save the value of the cells or if it isn't looking in the correct place.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim finalrow As Long

Dim Beskrivelse As String 'description of bet'
Dim Dato As Date 'date of bet'

Dim i As Integer 'row counter'

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FormelIndtastninger") 'needs to look up data from this specific sheet'
finalrow = sht.ListObjects("Data").Range.Rows.Count 'final row in Data table'

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 9) = "Ikke Afgjort" Then
        Beskrivelse = Cells(i, 6)
        Dato = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
Next

OpdaterIndtastning.DatoTekstboks.Text = Dato
OpdaterIndtastning.SpilTekstboks.Text = Beskrivelse

End Sub
```

Comment: `UserForm_Initialize` runs when the object gets instantiated, which makes it a very bad place to implement complex business logic. You'll probably want to move that code to a handler for the `Activated` event, but then you'll run into issues if the form isn't modal. How is it shown? If it's e.g. `UserForm1.Show`, you can probably fix the immediate problem by doing `With New UserForm1 / .Show / End With` instead, i.e. by *initializing* a new instance every time. How are you displaying that form?

Comment: Its shown when a button is pressed on a different worksheet

Comment: That is not the point/question. What matters is *when & how is the form instance created*. If you do `FormName.Show`, you can't expect code in your initialize handler to run every time. A form is an object, it wants to be treated as such: `New` it up.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. I haven't done the code for the button, but yeah it'd probably just be `.Show` 

Edit: Just read your link. You mention initialize is a bad way to go, with my very limited knowledge, would it be better to make a specific button on the userform that starts the search instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Mathieu Guindon's recommendation to use `UserForm_Activated` event not the `UserForm_Initialize` event.  Using Cell(row,column) won't work in the current context.  I think if you try the code below, you'll find your problem solved.

```
'Change finalrow from long to range
'Old Code Dim finalrow as Long
Dim finalrow as Range
Set finalrow = sht.ListObjects("Data").Range.Rows  'Sets finalrow = to entire data table range

'The range below as the index of your for loop
Dim aRow as Range
For Each aRow In finalrow 
    If aRow.Value2(1, 9) = "A" Then
        Beskrivelse = aRow.Value2(1, 6)
        Dato = aRow.Value2(1, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It works.  It does run from the buttom of the table and up, which i don't understand from the code, but i realised it'd be better that way, so thank you.

Comment: I apparently didn't understand it well enough. The "aRow" variable you define, doesn't that contain the row of the dataset, where the instance of "A" was found? I am trying to work upon the script and updating the information of column 9 and 10 in the row where the first instance of "A" was found.

Comment: The variable aRow is a Range Object and used as the Index in the `For Each` loop.  I keep your names like `finalrow` but it would be better named something like `sourceRange`.  You would have to replace "A" in my example code with whatever you are searching for that requires you update Beskrivelse and Dato.

Comment: I did update "A" to fit my code. What i believed i could, was to use the variable aRow in a different sub so that based on user input it could update the values in the columns of the row, where the function found "A"

Comment: The variable aRow contains a row of the data set. Prior to running your code, you should place a breakpoint on the `If aRow` statement.  Run the code, when it stops at the break point, look at `aRow` by either adding a watch, or through the locals window.  To open the Locals window, select it from the View menu.  To add breakpoints and watches, click on them under the Debug menu.  You'll find that aRow will have + sign.  When you click on it, it will expand to show you all the properties in a range.  Look for Value2 and see what's under there.  This may help explain what's going on.